# Удаление метки [руткод]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Метка [руткод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) относится к временам до эры ru.SO. Она не связана с тематикой сайта и должна быть удалена.

Comment: Согласен, но метку не вижу. Уже удалили?

Comment: Видимо, да. Там было всего 6 вопросов.